# dynamic height of child with parent height auto

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I don't know how long will be my title or sub-title be. So need the `height` of child inherited from parent. Any other way without specifying height to the parent ? Or can anyone point me to correct answer here, I couldn't find answers specific to my problem.

```css
.header {
  //height: 45px;
}
.header .col-xs-3 {
  border-right: 3px solid #efefef;
  height: inherit;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 header">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label>Title 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label>Title 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label>Title 3<br/>Sub-Title</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label>Title 4</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `flexbox` for the same.

CSS:

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  //height: 45px;
}
.header .col-xs-3 {
  border-right: 3px solid #efefef;
  height: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/fk6fs5ht/